# Path is abstract: cannot be instatiated(IntelliJ Ide)

Tags: java, file, path

I am trying to use the "import java.nio.file.Path" library in java, and i am getting a path is abstract, cannot be instantiated error. How should i go about fixing this error?

```
confHadoop.addResource(new Path("/opt/hadoop-2.7.3/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
```

Thanks

By the way, i am using intelliJ Ide*

Answer (score 4):

Use `Paths::get`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-

```
confHadoop.addResource(Paths.get("/opt/hadoop-2.7.3/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
```